# Register DOMContentLoaded in Google Chrome 

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

In Firefox and Safari i managed to register the DOMContentLoaded event with **window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', PageShowHandler, false);** by inserting this statement into the js script that gets inserted, or more clearly, get executed after the dom of the page is loaded, my specific functions managed to run at every time the DOM of this specific page was loaded.

I can't seem to do this in Chrome. I made some trick with the **chrome.tabs.onUpdated** et al events but it doesn't work in every instance; all these events don't add up to what the DOMContentLoaded achieves. For example when i click on specific links on my webpage this doesn't inject my code as my DOMContentLoaded event could have done.

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', PageShowHandler, false);
```

introduced into **inject.js** doesn't seem to register the event.

This is the manifest:

```
{
"name" : "gMail Adder ",
"version" : "1.0",
"description" : "Google Chrome Gmail Adder",
"options_page": "options.html",
"background_page": "background.html",
"run_at": "document_start",
"permissions": [
   "tabs",
   "history",
   "http://*/*",
   "https://*/*"
],
"content_scripts": [
  {
   "matches": ["*://*.google.mail.com/*", "https://*.google.mail.com/*"     ,"http://mail.google.com/*" ,"https://mail.google.com/*", "https://www.google.com/*", "http://www.google.com/*", "file:///*"],
   "css": ["toggle.css"],
   "js": ["jquery-1.4.4.min.js", "inject.js"]
  }
],
"browser_action" : {
"default_icon" : "Quest Icon 11.png",
"default_popup": "popup.html"
}
}
```

Comment: Chrome (by default) injects content scripts when dom is loaded, so that's probably why DOMContentLoaded is not triggered. What are you trying to achieve with DOMContentLoaded? Maybe you don't need it at all?

Comment: this is what i'm trying to achieve [link](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UyyYIQftZIs)

Comment: that is why i need to re-inject code into the DOM of the page from my popup.html .

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If you add `"run_at":"document_start"` flag to content scripts in the manifest they will be injected before DOM is constructed, so `DOMContentLoaded` should be triggered every time:

```
"content_scripts": [
  {
   "matches": ["*://*.google.mail.com/*", "https://*.google.mail.com/*"     ,"http://mail.google.com/*" ,"https://mail.google.com/*", "https://www.google.com/*", "http://www.google.com/*", "file:///*"],
   "css": ["toggle.css"],
   "js": ["jquery-1.4.4.min.js", "inject.js"],
   "run_at": "document_start"
  }
],
```

(more about execution order [here](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html))

Comment: \*sign\* - For `DOMContentLoaded` use `"document_end"` for `window.onload` use `"document_idle"`. Check out this template [https://github.com/eladkarako/my-chrome-extension-bootstrap](https://github.com/eladkarako/my-chrome-extension-bootstrap). *Maintaining an additional (your own) event-handler for DOMContentLoaded in the document life-cycle for extension is bad-practice, considering that webkit's engine provides you with one, that does not overburden the page.*

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get things working by using the **DOMFocusIn** event in my injected script. This event correctly mimics the trigger behavior that **DOMContentLoaded** achieves in Firefox and Safari.

```
window.addEventListener('DOMFocusIn', PageShowHandler, false);
```

This doesn't work properly if i don't set to **true** the **"all_frames"** field in **"contents_scripts"**:

```
{
"name" : "gMail Adder ",
"version" : "1.0",
"description" : "Google Chrome Gmail Adder",
"options_page": "options.html",
"background_page": "background.html",
"run_at": "document_start",
"permissions": [
   "tabs",
   "history",
   "http://*/*",
   "https://*/*"
],
"content_scripts": [
  {
   "matches": ["*://*.google.mail.com/*", "https://*.google.mail.com/*" ,"http://mail.google.com/*" ,"https://mail.google.com/*", "https://www.google.com/*", "http://www.google.com/*", "file:///*"],
   "css": ["toggle.css"],
   "js": ["jquery-1.4.4.min.js", "inject.js"],
   "all_frames" : true
  }
],
"browser_action" : {
"default_icon" : "Quest Icon 11.png",
"default_popup": "dialog.html"
}
}
```