# chrome extension page modification onload

Tags: google-chrome-extension, onload

I've looked for a solution to remove the content of a web page as soon as this page is loaded.

The simpliest manifest is:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Remove WebPage",
  "description": "Remove WebPage",
  "version": "0.2",

  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["http://www.webdomain.net/*"],
      "js": ["myscript.js"]
    }
  ],

  "permissions": [
    "tabs", 
    "http://*/", 
    "https://*/"
  ]
}
```

and the `myscript.js` file is

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', fireContentLoadedEvent, false);

function fireContentLoadedEvent () {
    document.body.textContent = "No data anymore";
}
```

It looks simple, but that does not work.

Comment: It pay's to learn [how English grammar work's](http://www.grammarbook.com/punctuation/apostro.asp). I'm going to edit the question for you, but please pay attention to spelling next time.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Register DOMContentLoaded in Google Chrome](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5082094/register-domcontentloaded-in-google-chrome)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Xan has already pointed out, your code is running too late.

The actual solution in your case should be:

1) Add `"run_at": "document_end"` to your manifest like this:

```
"content_scripts": [
    {
        "matches": ...,
        "js": ...,
        "run_at": "document_end"
    }
]
```

2) Remove `document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', fireContentLoadedEvent, false);` and directly call your function using `fireContentLoadedEvent()` or move your code out of the function altogether.

Answer (score 0):

Your script by default executes *after* `DOMContentLoaded` has fired. Therefore, your event handler is never triggered.

Have a look at [`run_at` parameter documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#run_at).