# Perform a click until the element can actually be clicked

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm using this javascript code:

```
document.getElementsByName("commit")[0].click();
```

to perform a click on a button, the problem is that when I send the command sometimes the page is't loaded , so it can't be clicked .
So how i can perform the click until it actually happens ?
i have tried something like this:

```
if (document.readyState === 'complete') { //don't work
document.getElementsByName("commit")[0].click();

}
```

but it doesn't work. (I can't use jquery, cause I'm on a chrome extension)

Comment: Something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9899372/pure-javascript-equivalent-of-jquerys-ready-how-to-call-a-function-when-t

Comment: Give something like this a shot:
`document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
 //code here
});` This is the equivalent to jQuery `document.ready`

Comment: The addEventListener isn't 100% cross browser

Comment: @devzero That is a good point. It is supported for Chrome though so that is why I thought it could be used for a Chrome Extension

Comment: @EliTownsend i have tried but it doesn't work. (document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { alert("aaaa"); });) it doesn't work unfortunatly

Comment: i have tried also to put in chorme console : it results  : undefined

Comment: @Marià You have an extra `;` Make the code this and it works `(document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { alert("aaaa"); }))`

Answer (score 0):

Firing it on the `DOMContentLoaded` event should do the trick

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    document.getElementsByName("commit")[0].click();
})
```

Comment: i have tried what you write , and i have also added an alert , but it does nothing even the alert

Comment: even if i put it in the chrome console it says: undefined

Comment: Well putting it in the console will return undefined since this isn't returning anything. See this question, it looks like updating the manifest will work, can you try that? 

https://stackoverflow.com/a/5082307/4869078

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
window.onload = function() {
   console.log("page loaded");
   //your code here
}
```

I would also be sure that you are including your javascript files at the bottom of the page and not the top.

Comment: it doen't return any arror but it doesn't work.. i have tried window.onload = function() {
   console.log("page loaded"); alert("loaded");
   //your code here
} but nothing

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
document.querySelector('#myBtn').addEventListener('click', function () {
 // do some stuff here
});
```

Comment: <input type="submit" name="commit" value="Add" class="button"> , this i s the button how i can edit the code to fit this button ?

Comment: beacuse it doen't have and id

Comment: change the '#myBtn' to '.button'

Comment: i have tryes  adding alert("aaa"); but it doesn't appear

Comment: Did you try to wrap the code above with DOMContentLoaded?

Comment: in which sense ?

Comment: <input id="click-this" type="submit" name="commit" value="Add" class="button"></input>

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    document.getElementById("click-this").addEventListener("click", handler);
  });

Comment: i can't change the button is a third part website , i can only use javascript from my chrome extension

Comment: Then change the getElementById to getElementsByClassName and call your className